# How can I "Running an app in Xcode but without debugger, and console is still accessible to an app as stdin, stdout, and stderr."?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I saw

> Note: Running an app within the Xcode environment but without
>   attaching to the debugger is also possible, in which case the console
>   is still accessible to an app as stdin, stdout, and stderr.

in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html

But I don't know how to do it? Can someone can help me?Many thanks!

Comment: Not sure about using Xcode for this use-case, but if your goal is simply to observe stdin/out/err messages, you can always run the app from the Terminal.

Comment: But this app which I want to run is an iOS app, Can it run from Terminal of Mac without Xcode?

Comment: That's a good question. I don't know, but have you tried running the simulator from the cmd line? I wonder if you get any info there?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your scheme so it uses the Release build configuration when running the app from Xcode. When you run the app from Xcode, it won't attach to the debugger.

[image]

You might also have to deselect the Debug executable checkbox.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this, and It seems Xcode output window will not print log that use stdout and stderr using this method.

Comment: I think if console is still accessible to an app as stdin, stdout, and stderr. It can output these log.

Comment: My answer covers running your project without attaching the debugger. I have no solution for your console logging issues. You should update your question with the problems you are having logging your output to the console.